# Ember: Merge Multiple Column of Arrays to rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, ember-data

I have to populate a grid in which each column's data comes as a array under the object as mentioned below where A and B are column names
and data structure as follows

```
{
    A:[1,2,3],
    B:[4,5,6]
}
```

So to render this as a table in template it will be easier if the columns are mergered into following structure

```
[
    [1,4],
    [2,5],
    [3,6]
]
```

Or it will be helpful if some one suggest some other better solution for this problem

Comment: @Xotic750 I have updated the question with the exact problem description

Comment: Does your object always have two keys `A` and `B`, are the arrays associated with `A` and `B` always the same length and matching lengths? Can you show us the code that you have tried and explain the difficulties that you are experiencing with your code?

Comment: @Xotic750 no the number of keys is unknown but the length of all the keys will be same all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common collection operation which is so-called **zip**.

With **underscore.js**, it is as simple as:

```
var input = {
    A:[1,2,3],
    B:[4,5,6],
    // C: [7,8,9], ... etc.
}
var inputArrays = _.values(input);
var zipped = _.zip.apply(null,inputArrays);
```

Or with simple JavaScript, you can just use loop to zip those two arrays:

```
var zipped = [];
var inputArrays = Object.keys(input).map(function(key){
    return input[key]
});
for (var i=0; i<inputArrays[0].length; i++){
    var element = inputArrays.map(function(m){
       return m[i]
    });
    zipped.push( element );
}
```

**EDIT NOTE**: Just got notified the object keys are variable. This solution should work fine and hopefully it is readable :)

Comment: The OP says: `the number of keys is unknown`

Comment: Thanks @Xotic750 for reminding me. I have now updated the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = {
    A: [1, 2, 3],
    B: [4, 5, 6]
  };



  var x = [
    [, ]
  ];

  for (i = 0; i < v.A.length + 1; i++) {

    x.push([v.A[i], v.B[i]]);
    alert(x[i, i]);
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments, you have not provided any code for correction/help, you probably want to do something like this.

```js
function customMerge(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (acc, key) {
        var items = obj[key];

        items.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (!acc[index]) {
                acc[index] = [];
            }

            acc[index].push(item);
        })

        return acc;
    }, []);
};

var data = {
    A: [1, 2, 3],
    B: [4, 5, 6],
    C: [7, 8, 9]
};

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(customMerge(data), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    A: [1, 2, 3],
    B: [4, 5, 6]
}
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var desiredStructure = obj[keys[0]].map(function(col,i){  
    return keys.map(function(_,j){ return obj[keys[j]][i] })
});
console.log(desiredStructure);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8z6wpjvw/)